Running simultaneous future_promise() in RShiny on Kubernetes/OpenShift
Problem statement
I'm creating an RShiny application with a long database call. As this blocks the main R thread, other users will not be helped by the server during the execution of this call. So I implemented a future_promise. (A more fleshed out example below).
 get_data <- function(query, con){
  result <- dbSendQuery(con, query)
  data <- fetch(result, n = -1)
  dbClearResult(result)
}

In the first place it seems to work, as other actions by users are indeed possible!
However *I'm running into trouble when 2 users start the future_promise process at the same time.
When this happens the entire server stops and top -H returns 99% cpu usage on the main R thread. This happens only on OpenShift which is basically Kubernetes. It might be related to it being linux/unix.
Things I've tried:

All execution plans: plan() documentation

The cluster plan seems to be the most reliable


The async library (but it builds on top of the future library)

Are the 2 workers overwriting each others memory?
Do I need to change settings in Kubernetes?
What are possible solutions?
FYI: It works fine on Windows, using the cluster plan, multiple tabs don't get stuck when executing the future_promise at the same time.
Code Example
Here is an example that simulates a long running process in the way I set it up:
1 running future_promise --> Application works fine
2 running future_promises (by 2 users) --> Application blocks (doesnt do anything)
library(shiny)
library(promises)
library(future)

# Plan for future to use multicore processing
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(parallelly::availableCores() -1)
plan(cluster, workers = cl)
plan(cluter)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Long Process with future_promise"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("start", "Start Long Process"),
      textOutput("status")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("result")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  result <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  status <- reactiveVal("Waiting to start...")
  

  # Problematic if 2 users do it at the same time
  observeEvent(input$start, {
    status("Processing...")
    future_promise({
      # Simulate a long process
      Sys.sleep(5)
      sum <- 0
      for (i in 1:1e6) {
        sum <- sum + i
      }
      sum
    }) %...>% {
      result(.)
      status("Process completed!")
    } %...!% {
      result(NULL)
      status("An error occurred.")
    }
  })

  output$status <- renderText({
    status()
  })

  output$result <- renderPrint({
    result()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)



I think using ExtendedTask might solve this: https://rstudio.github.io/shiny/reference/ExtendedTask.html

@smartse turns out in Kubernetes the same future being executed twice reads/writes to the same memory in the default plans (I think Windows guards against this, linux doesn't (by default)). https://future.callr.futureverse.org/reference/future.callr.html half resolved this. The futures always resolve, but it seems like same futures are still resolved consecutively. Even so; the main R interpreter stays free. Users that initiate the future_promise while someone else is running it have to just wait a bit longer (but the server keeps running). This is the next problem I will try to solve.
